# AWS SDK Promises callback on each promise

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-sdk, guzzle

I have a promise to send an email that works fine.

```
$promise = $this->SesClient->sendEmailAsync($messages[0]);

$promise->then(
    function ($value) {
        echo "The promise was fulfilled with {$value}";
    },
    function ($reason) {
        echo "The promise was rejected with {$reason}";
    }
);
```

However I want to be able to combine all of my emails and send them all in parallel while still having a callback. Depending on if the email sent successfully or failed I log it in my database.

I have something like this, which sends all of my emails fine, but how do I use ->then on each promise to then do an action for each one after it has completed?

```
$promises = [];

foreach($messages as $message) {
    $promises[] = $this->SesClient->sendEmailAsync($message['Email']);
}

$results = Promise\unwrap($promises);
```

Comment: Iterate over the messages with a regular loop, then put the n'th promise into your `$promises` array via `$promises[n] = ...sendEmailAsync(...)`, then you can access the results individually later after unwrap via `$results[n]`.

Comment: the issue is that I don't have the id for the database in the returned $results array. I also can't catch an exception if it fails, then the entire $results array cant be accessed.

Comment: What ID? You have the $messages array and you have the $results array. They map one-to-one. Iterate over both arrays at the same time. If PHP Promises/A+ doesn't provide an equivalent of the JavaScript `allSettled()` feature then presumably you don't have an option to a) run concurrently and b) not fail if an exception is thrown for one of the calls. In that case run them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

`GuzzleHttp\Promise` provides the end user with a fluent interface.  The result of a call to `GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromiseInterface::then` is an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromiseInterface`.  This permits end users with the ability to chain multiple `then()` blocks.

To complete multiple tasks on a per response basis, all one has to do is "chain" the then blocks

```
foreach($messages as $message) {
    $promises[] = $this->SesClient->sendEmailAsync($message['Email'])
                    ->then(function (SomeDataType $inputData) {
                        echo 'process some value in here';
                        return $processedValue
                    })
                    ->then(function (ProcessedDataType $value) {
                        echo 'store the processed value in the database';
                    });
}
```

It is even possible to pass values from one promise to the next.

More information on Guzzle Promises can be found [here](https://github.com/guzzle/promises)